# Is it acceptable/possible to award a bounty to one's own answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I have offered a bounty that expires tomorrow to my question [Highlighting line ranges in a lstlisting: partial solution, but expansion issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30877/highlighting-line-ranges-in-a-lstlisting-partial-solution-but-expansion-issues), as it did not get very much attention. The bounty didn't help much, though; so I did investigate further and came up with a workaround I have posted as as an answer. So far this is the only answer.

I know that it is considered as perfectly okay to accept one owns answer (especially if it is the only answer). However, should/can I also award the bounty to myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not possible any more. Have a look at:

- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) Question "Can I award a bounty to my own answer?"
- [I just awarded myself a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty/97802#97802), the answer

Comment: But if I read the first link correctly, you can award a bounty to yourself, but it gains you no reputation.  So should the answer to Daniel be "yes"?

Comment: @AlanMunn The second link said "no." If you consider 0 reputation as a bounty, it can be "yes". Perhaps somebody tries...

Comment: Awarding a bounty to one's own answer, even if it yields zero reputation, may be relevant for earning the "Altruist" and "Benefactor" badges.

Comment: @lockstep: Yes, if there is no other answer which you could give the bounty instead, which should not happen so often and wouldn't be an issue.